# Parsing JSON correctly through JsonTextWriter

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, json, kendo-ui

I was facing difficulty with binding my `JSON` data with `Kendo UI` grid but while searching a solution to this problem I came face to face with other one. That how to correctly parse JSON to match its correct format as mentioned by @Petur Subev [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675115/kendo-ui-grid-not-showing-json-data/15701888)

My current JSON is in this format:

```
//{"No":null,"Desc":"asfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasf","Date":"2013-03-27T00:00:00","Height":0,"Final":null}
//{"No":null,"Desc":"etwetwetwetwet","Date":"2013-03-27T00:00:00","Height":0,"Final":0}
```

But as pointed out it should be like this:

```
[{"No":null,"Desc":"asfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasf","Date":"2013-03-27T00:00:00","Height":0,"Final":null},
{"No":null,"Desc":"etwetwetwetwet","Date":"2013-03-27T00:00:00","Height":0,"Final":0},
{"No":null,"Desc":"asfasfasfskfjklajsfkjasklfjklasjfklajsfkljaklsfjklasjfkljasfkljlasf","Date":"2013-03-27T00:00:00","Height":0,"Final":0}]
```

Its difficult to understand that why is it this way as I am using prebuilt to function to create a JSON but still I am getting it wrong kindly help.

in `Model Code` i Have:

```
public object GetResult(string id)
{
    var sqlCom = new SqlCommand("SELECT [No],[Desc],[Date],[Height],[Final] FROM [cr_form] WHERE [uId]=@id;", sqlConn);
    sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
    JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(sw);
    var rcrds = GETSQLRESULTS(sqlCom);

    try
    {
        int i = 0;
        if (rcrds != null || rcrds.HasRows)
        {
            //jsonWriter.WriteStartObject();
            while (rcrds.Read())
            {
                jsonWriter.WriteStartObject(); //Changed
                for (int j = 0; j < rcrds.FieldCount; j++)
                {
                    jsonWriter.WritePropertyName(rcrds.GetName(j)); // column name
                    jsonWriter.WriteValue(rcrds.GetValue(j)); // value in column
                }
                i++;
                jsonWriter.WriteEndObject(); //Changed
            }
            //jsonWriter.WriteEndObject();

        }

    }

    catch (Exception ex) { }
    return jsonWriter;
}
```

in `Controller`

```
public ActionResult GetRecords()
{
    var usrObj = new User();
    var jsnRslt = usrObj.GetResult(Session["Id"].ToString());

//After Changes in the Model I am getting it in the required Array format:
//{"No":null,"Desc":"asfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasf","Date":"2013-03-27T00:00:00","Height":0,"Final":null}
//{"No":null,"Desc":"etwetwetwetwet","Date":"2013-03-27T00:00:00","Height":0,"Final":0}
//{"No":null,"Des...

    return Json(jsnRslt, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);            
}
```

---

After Adding `WriteStartArray();`

```
{[{"No":null,"Desc":"asfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasfasf","Date":"2013-03-27T00:00:00","Height":0,"Final":null},
{"No":null,"Desc":"etwetwetwetwet","Date":"2013-03-27T00:00:00","Height":0,"Final":0},
{"No":null,"Desc":"asfasfasfskfjklajsfkjasklfjklasjfklajsfkljaklsfjklasjfkljasfkljlasf","Date":"2013-03-27T00:00:00","Height":0,"Final":0},
{"No":null,"Desc":"hdfhdfhdfh","Date":"2013-04-04T00:00:00","Height":1,"Final":0}]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you building JSON in your GetResult method? Why are you writing such plumbing code instead of leaving this to the framework?

What you should focus on is your business logic.

Just define a model that will represent the data you want to return (you might need to adjust the types of your model properties depending on the column types in your database):

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int? No { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int? Height { get; set; }
    public int? Final { get; set; }
}
```

and then have your method return this model (in fact a collection of this model to be more precise):

```
public IEnumerable<MyModel> GetResult(string id)
{
    string connectionString = "...";
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [No],[Desc],[Date],[Height],[Final] FROM [cr_form] WHERE [uId]=@id;";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                yield return new MyModel
                {
                    No = GetValue(reader, "No"),
                    Desc = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Desc")),
                    Date = reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("Date")),
                    Height = GetValue(reader, "Height"),
                    Final = GetValue(reader, "Final"),
                };
            }
        }
    }
}

private static int? GetValue(DbDataReader reader, string columnName)
{
    var columnIndex = reader.GetOrdinal(columnName);
    if (!reader.IsDBNull(columnIndex))
    {
        return reader.GetInt32(columnIndex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Notice how I have removed the tr/catch logic because you were not doing anything useful in the catch statement and it is a bad idea to silently consume exceptions like that.

And finally in your controller action simply:

```
public ActionResult GetRecords()
{
    var usrObj = new User();
    var jsnRslt = usrObj.GetResult(Session["Id"].ToString());
    return Json(jsnRslt, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

As you can see in this example you shouldn't be worried about plumbing and JSON. You should work with strongly typed models and leave the framework do the serialization for you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just want to call [`WriteStartArray`](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextWriter_WriteStartArray.htm) at the start...

Sample code:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (var writer = new JsonTextWriter(Console.Out))
        {
            writer.WriteStartArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                writer.WriteStartObject();
                writer.WritePropertyName("Foo");
                writer.WriteValue(i);
                writer.WriteEnd();
            }
            writer.WriteEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[{"Foo":0},{"Foo":1},{"Foo":2},{"Foo":3},{"Foo":4}]
```

Comment: Done that, i think i have got the desired results.. I am just confused a little bit that why I am getting a starting bracket `{` at the start and closing `}` at the end. is this ok or wrong. I have updated my question kindly have a look and the new JSON.

Comment: @Maven: I suspect the `Json` method itself is wrapping your array in an object - so you're returning an object containing an array, rather than just an array. Given that you're calling the Json method in the first place, do you definitely need to do the rest of your JSON encoding yourself? As Darin says, you should be able to just return a collection.